# Calculating $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{3 + 2 \cos(t)}dt$ using Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

My complex analysis has the following exercise in the end of the Residue Theorem chapter:

> Evaluate the integral $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{3 + 2 \cos(t)}dt$$

Because this is the first exercise on the residue theorem they gave the following tip:

> consider the path $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ with $t \in [0,2\pi]$ and $$\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2+3z+1} dz$$

---

My approach

First I found all the singularities of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+3z+1}$ and called them the set $A$.

So now we have:

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2+3z+1} dz = 2\pi i \sum_{a\in A}\text{Res}(f,a) \text{Ind}_\gamma(a)$$

With $A=\{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5} - 3);-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5} + 3)\}$

Because: $\text{Ind}_\gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5} + 3)\right) = 0$ and $\text{Ind}_\gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5} - 3)\right) = 1$, we have that:

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2+3z+1} dz = 2\pi i \text{Res}(f,\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5} - 3))$$

I calculated that residue and got the following:

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2+3z+1} dz = \frac{2\pi i}{\sqrt{5}} $$

Because we have that $\int_\gamma f = \int_a^b f(\gamma)\gamma ' dt$ then we have:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}}{e^{2it}+3e^{it}+1} dz = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{5}} $$

But now I have no idea how I can relate this integral to the original integral $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{3 + 2 \cos(t)}dt$.

My questions are:

- Did I made any mistake?
- If not, how can I relate this to the original integral I was trying to solve.
- Imagine that I was asked to evaluate this integral but I was not given any tip, how do you find the complex function that you need to integrate over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint - note that:

$$\int _0 ^{2\pi} \frac{1}{3+2\cos(t)}dt\underset{z=e^{it}}=\int _{|z|=1} \frac{z^{-1}dz}{3+2\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}}dt =\int _{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2+3z+1}dt$$

Generally, the substitution $z=e^{it}$ is a standard way of turning rational trigonometric integrals into contour integrals, which can be solved using the residue theorem.

Answer (score 2):

> Did I made any mistake?

Nothing stands out to me as a mistake.

> If not, how can I relate this to the original integral I was trying to solve.

Your final integrand is
$$\frac{e^{it}}{e^{2it}+3e^{it}+1}=\frac{1}{e^{it}+3+e^{-it}}=\frac{1}{3+e^{it}+e^{-it}}=\frac{1}{3+2\cos(t)}$$

(Since $\cos(t)=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}2$.)

> Imagine that I was asked to evaluate this integral but I was not given any tip, how do you find the complex function that you need to integrate over?

The integrand was a rational expression in a trig function. Writing it as a rational expression in $e^{it}$ is something to try. And then a substitution leads to the integral from the hint.